# Angular - Populating JSON data in Select

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am populating `JSON` data in Select/options. The problem is once user selects an item, value attribute displays the selected `JSON` data (including itemID and itemName) rather than just displaying itemName. whats the best possible way to display selected itemName only?

Here is sample data and code:

```
JSON:

    scope.itemData = [{"itemId":1,"itemName":"Glo Light"}, 
    {"itemId":2,"itemName":"Star Light"},
    {"itemId":3,"itemName":"Aqua Light"}]
```

and

```
Code:
    <select ng-model="myItem"> 
        <option ng-repeat="item in itemData" value="item.itemId">
           {{item.itemName}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Value in option should be an angular expression.

```
    <select ng-model="myItem">
        <option ng-repeat="item in itemData" value="{{item.itemId}}">
         {{item.itemName}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

[***Fiddle demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/kPS27/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="myItem" ng-options="i.itemId as i.itemName for i in itemData"></select>
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82LrD/)**